# Customizing Workspaces

Tags: workspaces

I want the following customizations in Ubuntu 12.10

I will like to every work space to show a clear desktop (i.e. the files in the Desktop of Workspace one shouldn't show up in Workspace two etc).

A New Program will start in a new workspace (e.g. if pdf is running in workspace one a new pdf in workspace two should just open a new pdf in worspace one).

There should be a workspace indicator (I think workspace indicator works).

I have read through most of the questions here on Workspace customizations and it didn't seem to help (except workspace-indicator perhaps). Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!